# How to get non-German diaeresis in Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, libertine

I am using Linux Libertine with XeLaTeX extensively, however the German umlauts are irritating me – those letters don't fit well in Hungarian typography.

Up until now, I have used a patched OpenType version of the font called *[Magyar Linux Libertine](https://numbertext.org/linux/)*, however I would like a solution, that work out-of-the-box with the `libertine` package and XeLaTeX.

Comment: You should ask to the maintainer and developer of Libertinus to add a stylistic variant. As far as I know, Libertine is no longer maintained.

Comment: @egreg This has actually helped a lot. In `libertinus` StylisticSet 0 and 1 were swapped, so it does what I want by default.

Answer (score 1):

**Original answer:** It turns out that this is supported in the `libertine` package, I can just specify globally, that I want to use the first stylistic set:

```
\usepackage[defaultfeatures={StylisticSet=1}]{libertine}
```

This is mentioned on the third page of the [package documentation](https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/fonts/libertine/doc/libertine.pdf).

---

I can also specify it locally with `fontspec` and `\addfontfeature`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
    Ö Ü \\
    {\addfontfeature{StylisticSet={1}} Ö Ü} 
\end{document}
```

Note the difference:

[image: German vs. non-German style diaeresis]

---

**Updated answer:** The fork of *Linux Libertine*, *Libertinus* has fixed many issues with the font, among others, mine. Stylistic Set #0 and #1 were swapped, so non-German dieresis is the default now, this work just fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\begin{document}
    Ö
\end{document}
```